# Responsive Web Design with drastic layout changes

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've always wondered about this.

Even with media queries, how would I significantly change the placement of things(since I'm not modifying element placement in HTML directly).

For example, if social Facebook/Twitter links appear somewhere in the middle of the page(with their HTML container elements nested in a bunch of other parent tags), how would I go about moving that to the bottom of the page(or, to make it look like they are nested in a different section).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two options:

1. Change the positioning of the container element. Instead of static position (default behavior), you can use `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` to move it to a totally different place on your page.
2. Repeat the elements in two different places, and set one of them visible depending on a screen size.

I must add, however, that in a good design such measures are rarely necessary. You do not want to confuse your users by moving the elements to a totally different location. A better approach is to use a responsive grid (for example, changing the layout from three columns to two, or from two to one, when a screen gets smaller), collapse tabs into a drop-down list, etc., but keep the position of different elements relatively stable.

Answer (score 1):

Moving to the bottom of the page wouldn't be a big deal. Depending on the parent container, use `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` and adjust the `z-index` of this and the parent container.

However, if you wanted to re-order your containers for specific media queries, you'll either have to give absolute positioning to more elements, adjust your floats, or use Javascript.

If this is a client request, I would personally revisit the wireframe stage and plan your responsive behavior from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You never ever can assume height of elements for sure from a CSS perspective: user will zoom a bit or a lot, images included or not; images won't appear because of network problem or by user choice, etc. Thus `position: absolute` is a recipe for future or immediate failure (and `fixed` not what you're searching for).

You can play with:

- flexbox (horizontal or vertical, natural or reverse order)
- `display: table-(header|footer)-group` or `display: table-caption` along with `table-cell` and if possible with parent element having `display: table` (with or without `table-layout: fixed`) or `table-row`
- floats and [Block Formatting Context effects](http://www.cssmojo.com/block-formatting-contexts/) (such a powerful beast)
- nope: CSS Grid Layout is [IE10 and IE11 only](http://caniuse.com/css-grid)

If you want to move an element from somewhere inside some other element far away both in HTML and visually, then go with JS/jQuery. CSS doesn't allow for complex manipulations. Just make sure that you watch for resize both *from* and *to* desktop/mobile resolutions (and allow for initial manipulation and after some AJAX event) and don't fire 100+ events per second when resizing